# Property does not exist on type 'object' with Svelte (using TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm trying to pass objects from the array to components.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Like this:
[image: Example]

But it says that property title doesn't exist in this type.
[image: Example 2]

Also, the console log acts weirdly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not screenshot code, insert it as text and [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it.

Comment: Pictures of code can't be searched or copied by people trying to help you. It is also likely that many users will not be able to read your images, because of contrast, colour schemes of because they are using screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

You declare the property to be an `object` which specifies just about nothing, so of course the compiler will not know that there is a `title`. You have to be more specific (or tell the compiler to accept anything using `any` which is not recommended).

You can define a named interface or define the type inline:

```js
export let data: Data;

interface Data { title: string, desc: string, img: string, prize: number }
```

```js
export let data: { title: string, desc: string, img: string, prize: number };
```

(Btw, `prize` should probably be `price`.)

Comment: Specifying the full interface like it says in this answer is by far the best approach when it's plausible to do so, but there is an alternative to using `any` that gets just a bit closer by at least restricting it to an actual object:

```
export let data: Record<string, any>;
```